# Неверный вывод данных из таблицы

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, таблицы

Заполнил таблицу таким образом:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); j++) {
        ui->tableWidget->model()->setData(ui->tableWidget->model()->index(j, i), tr(" "));
    }
}
```

Далее сделал слот который вызывается каждые 1000 мс и там написал:

```
qDebug() << ui->tableWidget->model()->data(ui->tableWidget->model()->index(0, 0));
```

В "Вывод приложения" пишется:

```
QVariant(QString, " ")
```

Но написав:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В "Вывод приложения" пишется:

```
QVariant(QString, "1")
QVariant(QString, " ")
QVariant(QString, "1")
QVariant(QString, " ")
```

Comment: Что два раза? Из вашего вопроса непонятно куда и что пишется, надо больше информации

Comment: написал в конструкторе [1](https://yadi.sk/i/9dopKrvdfhRcHQ) и [2](https://yadi.sk/i/s7hHEYuDVdux5A), но в выводе пишется [3](https://yadi.sk/i/X6IEJoBl70hLPg)

Comment: но я запусти на другом устройстве данный проект и там пишется 1 раз, получается это баг qDebug()?

Comment: Наверное баг, или что-то еще. Отсюда не видно :) п.с. вот у вас там item2, а проверяете item, может быть еще есть какие-то неточности и опечатки

Comment: Ругался на item во втором случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы используете класс [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html), то наполнять его данными надо при помощи метода `QTableWidget::setItem` и объектов класса `QTableWidgetItem`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); j++) {
        QTableWidgetItem* item = new QTableWidgetItem();
       
        // Ячейка должна быть редактируема
        item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);

        item->setText(tr(""));
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i /*row*/, j /*column*/, item);
    }
}
```

Получение значения из ячейки:

```
QTableWidgetItem* item = ui->tableWidget->item(0 /*row*/, 0 /*column*/);
if ( item )
    qDebug() << item->text();
```

Если же вы непременно хотите воспользоваться моделью данных (как оболочкой для ваших, то есть пользовательских, данных), то воспользуйтесь классом [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) и классом [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) и его наследованием (или уже готовыми наследниками)

Comment: Написал вышеперечисленное в конструкторе, но в "Выводе приложения" всё равно qDebug() пишет два раза